# Integrate VAST compliant video player into a windows application

Tags: windows, video, vast

We currently play videos in our windows application using Flash.ocx but we need to change to a VAST compliant solution...

Can anyone make any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty if video players supporting VAST (both HTML and Flash), some of them have native support of VAST1/2/3 and VPAID1/2, and some just need the plugins:

- [Veeplay](http://veeplay.com/)
- [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/)
- [Projekktor](http://www.projekktor.com/)
- [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org)

And free and open source [Video.JS](http://www.videojs.com/)

They are basically design for web, but anyway if you need to play VAST compliant ad that goes from web, you can just implement that players anywhere.